# Input data on Web using VBA

Tags: javascript, vba, internet-explorer

I'm having trouble using VBA to fill this input. I've tried `IE.Document.getelementsbyname("pienmr")(0).value` but it's not working.

Code:

```html
<td class=champtd width="25%">
    <input onchange=checkPie(this) maxLength=10 size=22 value=165662533R 
           name=pienmr notwith="ecartsigle_checked" 
           txt_notwith="Pour pièce en écart de sigle, les seuls paramètres possibles sont l'approvisionneur et la famille">
</td>
```

It's an internal company website, so, which it's only able to access using vpn. I have a fell practice to use VBA on web, but I'm having trouble to work on it.

P.s.: Can someone help me to suggest something to improve my VBA skills on acessing web?

Update:
Actually, all I need is to change the value of "165662533R" using vba

Comment: No URL and "not working" doesn't give us much to work with...

Comment: I think you question needs more clarification, what do you want to achieve? which part do you want access to? I agree with @TimWilliams that you give to little information to work with.

Comment: It's an internal company website that's why I can't give to you an url. I need to fill the form on that code.

Comment: @Wizhi - May I call in contact with you? I don't know if it's possible to send messages here on stackoverflow.

Comment: @GustavoSarturi did you tried to fire the change event after setting the value in the input field as I show you in the sample code?. Does the suggestion I provided you in the answer to help you to get the answer for your question? If yes, you can try to accept the answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT - I'll try and then, I text to you here

Answer (score 0):

syntax: assign value to variable

var x = document.getElementsByName("pienmr")[0].value;

see https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp

Comment: I`ll try it. Thank you.

Comment: No square brackets in VBA [for collection/array indexing] though

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you can see the new text entered in the textbox but the site shows some kind of error?

I can see that the input field has the **checkPie(this)** function on the **Onchange** event.

It can be possible that you are not firing this function from your code causing this issue.

Here is the sample that you can try to refer which shows you how to fire the change event after setting the value in the input field.

```
Sub demo()

    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As Object
   
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
 
    URL = "https://example.com"

    IE.Navigate URL
     
    Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
   
    Set ieEvent = IE.document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
    ieEvent.initEvent "change", False, True
       
    IE.document.getelementsbyname("pienmr")(0).Value = "ABC"
    IE.document.all.Item("pienmr").dispatchEvent ieEvent
    
    Set IE = Nothing
   
End Sub
```

You can try to test this code on your side and let us know if you have further questions.

Comment: It appears the Following error:
Run Time Error '462': The remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable

Comment: On which line you get this error? Make sure that you have properly added the necessary references to your code and objects are assigned properly.

Comment: It starts when goes to "Do Until..."

Comment: I've use Selenium to VBA and it works completely. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Its good to know that you have found the workaround for the issue. I have seen some threads where code gets stuck on the ready state loop. To quickly check it, you can try to comment that 2 lines of the loop and try to steps into the code using the F8 key. You will notice that your code will work. In that situation, you can try to use any other code to check the ready state or try to update your MS Office and Windows OS that may help to fix the issue.